# Cronômetro usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o código a seguir, o cronômetro funciona, porém quando chega ao fim ele mostra FIM e reinicia. Eu queria que ele parasse na mensagem FIM.

```
var tempo = new Number();
// Tempo em segundos
tempo = 10;

function startCountdown(){

// Se o tempo não for zerado
if((tempo - 1) >= 0){

    // Pega a parte inteira dos minutos
    var min = parseInt(tempo/60);
    // Calcula os segundos restantes
    var seg = tempo%60;

    // Formata o número menor que dez, ex: 08, 07, ...
    if(min < 10){
        min = "0"+min;
        min = min.substr(0, 2);
    }
    if(seg <=9){
        seg = "0"+seg;
    }

    // Cria a variável para formatar no estilo hora/cronômetro
    horaImprimivel = min + ':' + seg;
    //JQuery pra setar o valor
    $("#tempo").html(horaImprimivel);

    // Define que a função será executada novamente em 1000ms = 1 segundo
    setTimeout('startCountdown()',1000);

    // diminui o tempo
    tempo--;

// Quando o contador chegar a zero faz esta ação
} else {
    if (tempo == 0){
    fim = "FIM";
    $("#tempo").html(fim);
    }
}

}

// Chama a função ao carregar a tela
startCountdown();
```

Comment: O código que você tem não continua para além da mensagem de FIM. [Veja ele a funcionar no JSFiddle tal como tem na pergunta](http://jsfiddle.net/dku54zvh/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia usar a declaração `return`, já ouviu falar?

> Definição: A declaração return em javascript encerra a execução da função e retorna o valor para cada função. Se o valor for omitido, será retornado **undefined**. Fonte: https://www.w3.org

Nesse caso, ao entrar no seu else e setar o valor "FIM" pra sua variável *tempo* você poderia adicionar a declaração return para parar a execução como você deseja.

O **trecho** código ficaria assim:

```
. . . else {
    if (tempo == 0){
    fim = "FIM";
    $("#tempo").html(fim);
    return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apenas inseri um controle de booleano no código para identificar se ele terminou o processo ou não, criando a variável `done`. Essa variável é sempre checada no inicio do contador.

```js
var tempo = new Number();
// Tempo em segundos
tempo = 10;
done = false;

function startCountdown() {

  // Se o tempo não for zerado
  if ((tempo - 1) >= 0 && done == false) {

    // Pega a parte inteira dos minutos
    var min = parseInt(tempo / 60);
    // Calcula os segundos restantes
    var seg = tempo % 60;

    // Formata o número menor que dez, ex: 08, 07, ...
    if (min < 10) {
      min = "0" + min;
      min = min.substr(0, 2);
    }
    if (seg <= 9) {
      seg = "0" + seg;
    }

    // Cria a variável para formatar no estilo hora/cronômetro
    horaImprimivel = min + ':' + seg;
    //JQuery pra setar o valor
    $("#tempo").html(horaImprimivel);

    // Define que a função será executada novamente em 1000ms = 1 segundo
    setTimeout('startCountdown()', 1000);

    // diminui o tempo
    tempo--;

    // Quando o contador chegar a zero faz esta ação
  } else {
    if (tempo == 0) {
      done = true;
      fim = "FIM";
      $("#tempo").html(fim);
    }
  }

}
```